# GLM with three categorial predictors (including time)

Tags: r, time-series, hypothesis-testing, generalized-linear-model, post-hoc

I was collecting data on formation of intracellular foci in cells. I counted percent of cells with foci at three different timepoints (1, 2 and 3) for three genotypes (A, B, and C) and two disease states (healthy and diseased) for a total of five biological replicates. My expectation is that foci increase over time.

The questions I would like to address are: **Which influence does the genotype and the disease state have on this formation of foci over time? And is there maybe also an interaction between them?**

When I thought about data analysis before I started the experiments I planned to do a three-way ANOVA. However, I now face the problem that the data doesn't follow normal distribution and doesn't show homogeneous variances. Regarding the normal distribution, well I could have thought about that earlier as one can expect this when using counts.

Now my plan would be to fit a generalized linear model. As I never did this, I am not quite sure if I am doing everything correct. I would be happy to hear your ideas - especially if you think this is the wrong approach. Here is my code in R:

```
tp <- c(rep(1, 36), rep(2, 30), rep(3, 30)) # timepoint
tp <- as.factor(tp)
gt <- c(rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 6, times = 2), rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 5, times = 4)) # genotype
ds <- c(rep(c("healthy", "diseases"), each = 18, times = 1), rep(c("healthy", "diseases"), each = 15, times = 2)) # disease state
pa <- c(0.0000,  0.5000,  0.0000,  1.9000,  0.4000,  1.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000,  7.3000,  7.9000,  6.9000,  1.8000,  1.4000, 
    3.2000,  3.5000, 5.3000,  4.5000,  3.8000,  0.0000,  1.0000,  6.8000,  0.5000,  0.5000,  2.0000,  1.6000,  5.5000,
    7.6000,  6.4000,  6.4000,  2.5000, 0.0000, 9.9000,  5.0000,  2.5000,  2.0000,  4.0000,  0.5000,  2.0000,  2.7000,
    0.0000,  1.0000,  1.0000,  3.7000,  2.7000,  4.8000, 0.5000,  0.0000,  3.2000,  2.5000,  1.5000,  5.8000,  5.4000,
    1.5000,  1.1000,  1.4000,  2.4000, 11.3000, 13.5000,  9.2000,  6.7000, 29.0175, 10.4000, 19.2000,  9.4000, 20.2000,
    3.5000,  0.7000,  0.9000,  2.9000,  1.0000,  0.5000,  8.2000,  1.0000,  7.2000,  4.3000, 6.4000,  0.8000,  1.3000,
    0.5000,  1.5000,  3.7000, 28.8000, 57.1000, 32.1000,  5.5000, 32.4000, 55.4000, 26.7000, 36.9000, 38.0000, 27.4000,
    61.1000, 44.0000, 41.6000, 44.8000,  6.4000) # percent cells with foci

data <- data.frame(tp, gt, ds, pa) # create data.frame
plot.design(pa ~ ., data = data) # plot the means

data.fit <- glm(pa ~ factor(tp)*factor(gt)*factor(ds), data=data, family=poisson()) # fit model

summary(data.fit)

lsmeans(data.fit, pairwise ~ tp*gt*ds) # calculate p-values for the differences
```

Comment: Your outcome variable is a fractional percentage. A Poisson regression is not appropriate for such data, as far as I know. You could use Poisson regression if you had the counts as dependent variable. One possibility with percentages is to use a GLM with a binomial distribution and a logit-link and possibly with robust variance estimation (using the sandwhich package in `R`). For more information, see [here](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stata/faq/how-does-one-do-regression-when-the-dependent-variable-is-a-proportion/). [Beta-regression](https://goo.gl/JzchR1) is also possible.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I tried a beta-regression which seems to work quite well. However, is it fine to call for the contrasts using lsmeans? I saw that usually glh is used here?

Comment: lsmeans is deprecated. Use `emmeans` instead. But yes, it's okay to use that. `glht` from the `multcomp` package is also fine.